# Bad State: Field does not exist within the Document Snapshot Platform ---FLUTTER

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve data from the fire store(Firebase) and then populate my Data Table with the fields I will be getting from the fire store. For this purpose, I am using a stream builder but I am getting this error:

> Field does not exist within the Document Snapshot Platform

I have checked the spellings but still, the issue is not resolved.

Here is my code and snapshots of Firebase and my Mobile screen.

```
class CaShBookRegister extends StatefulWidget {
  const CaShBookRegister({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CaShBookRegisterState createState() => _CaShBookRegisterState();
}

class _CaShBookRegisterState extends State<CaShBookRegister> {
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  DateTime date = DateTime.now();
  late var formattedDate = DateFormat('d-MMM-yy').format(date);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 16.0,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: ReuseableCard(
                      textcolour: Colors.white,
                      buttonColour: Colors.green,
                      text: "Cash in hand",
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8.0,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ReuseableCard(
                      buttonColour: Colors.red,
                      textcolour: Colors.white,
                      text: "Today's balance",
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot?>(
                stream: _firestore.collection('cashOut').snapshots(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    List<DataCell> displayedDataCell = [];

                    for (var item in snapshot.data!.docs) {
                      displayedDataCell.add(
                        DataCell(
                          Text(
                            item['amount'].toString(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                      displayedDataCell.add(
                        DataCell(
                          Text(
                            item['optionalDetail'].toString(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                      displayedDataCell.add(
                        DataCell(
                          Text(
                            item['datereceived'].toString(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    return FittedBox(
                      child: DataTable(
                        columns: const <DataColumn>[
                          DataColumn(
                            label: Text(
                              'Date',
                            ),
                          ),
                          DataColumn(
                            label: Text(
                              'Amount',
                            ),
                          ),
                          DataColumn(
                            label: Text(
                              'Optional Detail',
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                        rows: <DataRow>[
                          DataRow(cells: displayedDataCell),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                },
              ),
            ),
            const Spacer(),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: ReusableButton(
                    text: "Cash out",
                  )),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 8.0,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ReusableButton(
                      text: "Cash in",
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Snapshot offirestore]

[Snapshot of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sq9Vu.jpg)

Comment: I think you are missing a `data()` tag, maybe it should be `item.data()["amount"]` etc.

Comment: I've tried this and now I am getting another error.. "the method [] can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can't be null"

Comment: Try check the value against null, use ? or ! etc.

Comment: Added a null check! But still the same error.. Actually I removed data () tag after reading a post where they were saying after recent update you don't need to use this. data()

Comment: I don't know if it helps but in `StreamBuilder` I always check first for `snapshot.hasError`, then `snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting`, and only after this I use the returned snapshot.

Comment: Have you tried `Firestore.instance.collection("cashOut").snapshots(),` instead of `_firestore.collection('cashOut').snapshots(),` without declaring `final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;` as [shown in this example](https://gist.github.com/branflake2267/0a280f880a765e4847b11aa69dab9bc4)?